# MySQL get title from parentid with two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to explain much as possible. here is my query..

```
SELECT * FROM mm_star_ratings s
JOIN mm_posts p ON s.post_id = p.postid
WHERE p.type='B'
ORDER BY s.rating DESC LIMIT 5
```

`type='B'` is the main post and `type='C'` is the reply on that post. There is a `parentid` column in `mm_posts` to set main post `(B)` id for `C`. Do I want to get the `title` from `mm_posts` if `type='C'` is there anyway?

The challenge for me is to get it work with my rating table where `post_id` is set for both `B` and `C`

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: Thanks for giving a vote to CLOSE.see the answer below given by @Mahesh Madushanka at least he understood my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Following query,

```
SELECT s.*,p.*, IF(p.type='C',pp.title,p.title) as title FROM mm_star_ratings s
JOIN mm_posts p ON s.post_id = p.postid Left Join mm_posts pp on pp.postid=p.parent_id 
ORDER BY s.rating DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: without adding s.* and p.* you can specify required columns

Comment: Ah! I am adding it so I can dynamically switch the type to use single query for `B` and `C` I hope it is the correct way!

Comment: @CodeLover : Yes thats ok.